# Conditional Automake compilation for ARM A-32?

Tags: arm, autotools, automake

I have a source file that needs to be compiled for ARM A-32. A-32 includes ARMv4 and ARMv7 (but not Aarch32 or Aarch64). Our GNU makefile has:

```
IS_ARM32 := $(shell echo "$(HOSTX)" | $(GREP) -i -c -E 'arm|armhf|arm7l|eabihf')
...

ifeq ($(IS_ARM32),1)
AES_ARCH = -march=armv7-a -marm
SRCS += aes-armv4.S
endif
...

ifeq ($(IS_ARM32),1)
aes-armv4.o : aes-armv4.S
    $(CC) $(strip $(CXXFLAGS) $(AES_ARCH) -mfloat-abi=$(FP_ABI) -c) $<
endif
```

According to the [Conditional Compilation using Automake Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Limits-of-Conditionals.html#Limits-of-Conditionals) manual:

> An often simpler way to compile source files conditionally is to use
>   Automake conditionals. For instance, you could use this Makefile.am
>   construct to build the same hello example:
>
> ```
> bin_PROGRAMS = hello
> if LINUX
> hello_SOURCES = hello-linux.c hello-common.c
> else
> hello_SOURCES = hello-generic.c hello-common.c
> endif
> ```
>
> In this case, configure.ac should setup the LINUX conditional using
>   AM_CONDITIONAL (see [Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)).

Following the link to conditionals I don't see a list of the conditionals like `LINUX` as used in the example. It also lacks a discussion of conditional compilation for architectures, like ARM and PowerPC.

What conditional does Automake use for ARM A-32?

Or how does one conditionally compile for ARM A-32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Following the link to conditionals I don't see a list of the
>   conditionals like `LINUX` in the manual's example. It also lacks a
>   discussion of conditional compilation for platforms, like ARM and
>   PowerPC.

You appear to have overlooked this text from the quoted excerpt of the manual:

> > In this case, configure.ac should setup the LINUX conditional using
> >     AM_CONDITIONAL

`AM_CONDITIONAL` is the Autoconf macro with which you define a predicate for use in an Automake conditional.  There are no premade predicates.

> What does Automake use for ARM A-32?
>
> Or how does one conditionally compile for ARM A-32?

Given that your existing approach is based on

> ```
> IS_ARM32 := $(shell echo "$(HOSTX)" | $(GREP) -i -c -E 'arm|armhf|arm7l|eabihf')
> ```

you might do this in `configure.ac`:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([ARM32], [echo "$HOSTX" | $GREP -i -c -E 'arm|armhf|arm7l|eabihf'])
```

This assumes that `HOSTX` and `GREP` are autoconf output variables whose values have already been set.  If that's not the case for you then I'm sure that it at least provides a model for you to start with.

With the `ARM32` predicate defined in your configure.ac, you can then use it in your `Makefile.am` files much as in the example from the manual:

```
if ARM32
hello_SOURCES = hello-arm32.c hello-common.c
else
hello_SOURCES = hello-generic.c hello-common.c
endif
```